# Get User picture From Blob

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

We have a table where the user picture is stored in Oracle(As BloB) and I want to use that picture in Profiles. Can someone explain a little bit how to create a timer job for this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to adapt this to your need.

```
foreach (row dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string fileName = "SOMETHING.JPG";
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] imageContent = (byte[])((dRow["PhotoField"]));
            w.Write(imageContent);
        }
    }
```